# React Native touch is not working on Samsung devices

Tags: react-native

I have a problem only with physical Samsung devices,

This code sample is a button inside a rotating circular menu.

```
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPressIn={() => {
      navigate("customPage", { id: ID });
    }}
    style={{ ...style, ...styles.button }}
  >
    <Text style={[styles.textStyle, textStyle]}>{children}</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

I used `onPressIn` as `onPress` wasn't working with Samsung devices.

Using `onPressIn` sometimes works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small syntax error. The property is onPress, not onPressIn.

Try

```
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => {
      navigate("customPage", { id: ID });
    }}
    style={{ ...style, ...styles.button }}
  >
    <Text style={[styles.textStyle, textStyle]}>{children}</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I used onPressIn as onPress is not working at all, but onPressIn sometimes works and sometimes not.